# Orientation with tabbar problem

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, tabbar

I have a problem with my tabbar application..
My app can change orientation but when I'm on landscape in (for exemple) my first tab, everything work great, everything is replace but if I stay in landscape and I go in an other tab, the app still on landscape view (that's good) but the objects (labels, buttons, images,..) are not where it should be...

For check if the devise is in landscape or portrait, I use this

```
    -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
   If (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortait)
   { 
    image1.hidden = NO;
   }
  else
   {
    image2.hidden = YES;
   }
}
```

It work but I have to change the orientation when I want to go on an other...
Hope someone can help me..

Thanks :)

Comment: a comparison screenshot will be great (before and after)

Comment: Before and after what ? the problem is that the orientation work but tab by tab..

Comment: tab's view (incorrect) before you change the orientation and after (correct one) when you changes the orientation to portrait and then back to landscape.

Comment: it would be great if you could provide some relevant code from that uiewcontroller as well..

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your viewcontrollers within the tabs are returning YES for landscape orientation in

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```